# Call .bat script from inside VB.NET form application

Tags: vb.net, batch-file

I have a batch script that I have loaded into my solution. How can I reference this from the VB.NET application I am building to execute it?

Rather than

```
Shell.execute("C:\Users\Me\Desktop\application.bat")
```

How can I call the `application.bat` that is packaged within my solution?

Answer (score 2):

Get the startup path of your application using Application.StartupPath and append it to your .bat file name.

Comment: Make sure the .bat file is part of your project and marked as content to be copied in the bin folder.